# Rails download zip from binary data stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, zip, binaryfiles

I have a data-API to receive data from the file system. The data-API is a nodeJS server. Our webserver is a Rails server. From the webserver I send parameters to the API which files I want to download. The data-API then zips the request files and sends the zip back as binary data.

So far everything works fine. Now come the part where I'm stuck. I want to present the binary data as a download to the browser. I can either convert the binary data into a zip file and send that to the browser or have another clever solution that will present the binary data as a download.

Here's what I've got so far

Rails webserver side:

```
app/controllers/simulation_controller.rb

def download_multiple
  files = JSON.parse(params[:files])
  file_list = @simulation.sweep_points.find(params[:sweep_point_id]).file_list
  send_data file_list.zip(files: files), filename: 'archive.zip', type: 'application/zip', disposition: 'attachment'
end

app/models/file_list.rb

def zip
  uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
  simulation = sweep_point.simulation
  files = files[:files].join(" ")
  url = URI.parse("http://localhost:3003/files/zip/#{simulation.name}/#{uuid}");
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
  req.add_field("files", files)
  res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |http| http.request(req) }
  content = res.body
  content.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")
end
```

nodeJS data-API side:

```
exports.zip_simulation_files = (req, res) => {
  const { headers, method, url } = req;
  var simulation = req.params.simulation;
  var uuid = req.params.uuid;
  var files, command;

  req.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });

  files = req.headers.files;
  command = "cd postprocess/bumblebee-zip " +  "run" + simulation + " " + uuid + " " + "'" + files + "'";

  execute(command, (data) => {
    res.on("error", (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });

    const zipFilePath = "/home/samuel/test_bumblebee/.zips/run" + simulation + "-files-" + uuid + ".zip"

    var zipFile = fs.readFileSync(zipFilePath);
    var stats = fs.statSync(zipFilePath);
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="archive.zip"',
      'Content-Length': stats.size,
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary'
    });
    res.end(zipFile, 'binary');
  });
}
```

So far I'm getting back a response that is a string which seems to be a binary string. Which starts and end with this:

> "PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\b\x00\xA8\x89\xDBJ\xB1\xB8\xA1\xBF2\x03\x00\x00\xB7F\x00\x006\x00\x1C\x00runZhangD3FINAL/13.0V/annihilation_abs_profile_001.outUT\t\x00\x0          ....... x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x05\x00l\x02\x00\x00)\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00"

I've looked into different solutions in trying to turn the binary data string into a zip file or presenting the stream directly to the browser but nothing worked. Either the zip is not created or the binary was not seen as proper data.

What would be a good solution?

Comment: Can you attach an example binary string (whole) that you receive? I think the easiest solution would be to save the string to temp file (binary mode) and then send it to the browser using `send_data`.

Comment: Thanks @MrShemek for your reply. I've ended up creating a temporary zip file using IO::File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/test.zip", "w+b") { |f| f.write(res.body) } in my file_list.rb. From there I will send the file to the browser as a download.